# Installing the Android USB Driver in Windows 7

Tags: android, usb-drive

I am attempting to install the Android USB Driver in my computer running on Windows 7. I followed the instructions in the developer section of the website, but I am stuck. Here is the website with the instructions;

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Win7

What I am having trouble with is in step 7-8, when I click next after selecting the path `<sdk>/extras/google/usb_driver` under where I enter the location. I get an error message that says "Windows could not find driver software for your device"

I have tried looking for help in the Developers website, but it's so difficult to navigate that I am asking here.

I am positive that, under Computer Management, I am choosing the Android device under Other devices, which another question I have is that two "Android" drivers are showing up, but I figured this was due to me owning a previous phone with Android. See screenshot;

[image: Selecting the Android driver to update]

My phone is plugged in to my computer and USB debugging is checked in my phone. I own a Samsung Ace II.

Comment: Try Rightclick on a device --> Update Driver --> Search on my computer for drivers... ->  Choose from a list of driver. In the left column by manufacturer choose Samsung (there may be different ones, check each of them), choose ADB USB Driver (or somethign similar). Tell me if it worked

Comment: For Samsung devices, use the USB Driver Package provided by Samsung.

Comment: ^Where would this USB driver package be located? I believe Santhosh asked the same question in the answer posted below

Comment: Google "Samsung USB Driver for Mobile Phones", there are a few copies floating about.

Comment: here is the SAMSUNG USB DRIVER PACKAGE http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows

Comment: how is this off topic?

Comment: the Samsung USB driver package doesn't seem to support the Galaxy View

Answer (score 6):

Just download and install "Samsung Kies" from this [link](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP). and everything would work as required.

Before installing, uninstall the drivers you have installed for your device.

**Update:**

Two possible solutions:

1. Try with the Google USB driver which comes with the SDK.
2. Download and install the Samsung USB driver from this [link](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows) as suggested by [Mauricio Gracia Gutierrez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461862/mauricio-gracia-gutierrez)

Comment: No, don't download KIES. It's complete overkill. Samsung provides a separate driver package.

Comment: ok. Since he owns a Samsung device I thought it would be nice to have kies to transfer files, save messages, do backup and etc., Anyhow, where can we find this driver package.?

Comment: no need to downloa KIES.Here is the SAMSUNG USB DRIVER PACKAGE http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows

Comment: Thank.. the solution provided by  Mauricio Gracia worked for me..

Comment: You may need to download KIES, which is more update to date. The separate driver on the other hand is quite dated. Just uninstall the rest of the KIES parts you don't need and leave the driver.

Comment: Had to install the entire KIES (2.6) to get the most up to date drivers. Installation is only a few minutes. Previously to this the zipped drivers mentioned above failed to install on my Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Not working for me I downloaded and installed still it is not identify Android_samsung and CDC serial :(

Comment: The link is from Feb 10, 2015, here's a newer one: http://samsungusbdriver.com/download/samsung-driver-v1-5-60-0

Comment: 2. Solved the issue for me. Thanks.