# Android phone No driver found/installed

Tags: android, adb

When I connect my phone running android version 4.2.2 through the usb port the android phone driver is not installed. What could be the issue?  I have searched a lot but could not find a solution.
 Any insights would be greatly appreciated.
**EDIT:**
Usb debugging is enabled.
Phone Model and Make: Huawei 3c Honor (Just in case)

**Update:**
Question that may also be related or helpful but without answer given to my question: [Installing the Android USB Driver in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230189/installing-the-android-usb-driver-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows you can just go to your device manager, click the unknown android device and install the driver which you can find in the follow directory. You have to pick it manually as scanning the directory for matching device drivers will show an empty list of compatible drivers.

```
<path to your android sdk directory>\extras\google\usb_driver
```

Is your phone showing the USB debuggging connected mode? Otherwise you might have to enable this in the developers settings.

Comment: went to the above mentioned path it says that windows did not find driver software for your device. I have enabled usb debugging still  not able to do it

Comment: Click on your device in the device manager, driver tab, update driver, browse computer for driver software, let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer, select the driver and finally force feed it by telling windows you really want to install it.