# Can't usb debug, device doesn't show

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I wish to test my android app on my phone, but my device does not show in the list
Have followed all the tips in this thread - [Installing the Android USB Driver in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230189/installing-the-android-usb-driver-in-windows-7)
And followed this - 
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb

I have tried locating both the USB debug driver installed via android studio and also the samsung one i downloaded.. neither work
I get the error windows was unable to install your SAMSUNG_Android.
C:\Program Files\SAMSUNG\USB Drivers is the folder I select to install drivers from..

Info:
Windows 7
Galaxy s4 mini

Comment: Enable usb debugging feature. Then turn on usb debugging. It will work. Then allow, it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for me was changing the usb connection from MTP to PTP. Which interestingly isn't mentioned on the official android dev site.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install adb driver for your device from [here](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/)

and now turn usb debuging on and install required driver by selecting your device and click install button at the bottom

Hope it works